# Objective C NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I would like to append data to `NSArray` and than get count of data in `NArray` and retrieve data at specific `index`.

I am adding data as follows:

```
NSArray *oneInfo = @[
                     @{@"trackTime" :theTrack[@"seconds"],
                       @"trackPrice":theTrack[@"price"  ],
                       @"trackWait" :theTrack[@"wait"   ]
                      }
                    ];
```

Comment: What did you try? What does not work?

Comment: NSArray is immutable collection. if you want to change it, use [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I have made 'NSMutableArray' and using '[mutableArray addObject:oneInfo]' but after that it is still nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is an array literal which means it is immutable.  In order to make an array that you can change, do this:

```
NSArray *oneInfo = @[@{@"trackTime":theTrack[@"seconds"],@"trackPrice":theTrack[@"price"],@"trackWait":theTrack[@"wait"]}];
NSMutableArray* somethingICanChange = [oneInfo mutableCopy];
[somethingICanChange addObject: moreData];
```

Note that, if you are not using ARC (why not?), `somethingICanChange` is an array that you own and needs to be released or autoreleased when you are done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not append `NSArray` you have to create `NSMutableArray` for appending and other changes your need.

Answer (score 0):

`oneInfo = [oneInfo arrayByAddingObject: something];`